# Laravel migration mix up with person/people table names

Tags: laravel

For some reason Laravel is getting mixed up pluralizing person/persons some reason it assumes my table is people.

I know how to get around this without manually specify the table name inside the `$table->foreignId('person_id')->constrained('persons')` but I wanted to know why it happens? And which tables names to avoid/watch out for.

> Can't create table
> `person_logs` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly
> formed") (SQL: alter table `person_logs` add constraint
> `person_logs_person_id_foreign` foreign key (`person_id`) references
> `people` (`id`))

```
Schema::create('persons', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id('id');
    
    $table->string('firstname');
    $table->string('lastname');
});

Schema::create('person_logs', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id('id');
    
    $table->string('example');
    
    $table->foreignId('person_id')->constrained();
});
```

Comment: Laravel's [Pluralizer](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Support/Pluralizer.php) uses doctrine's [Inflector](https://github.com/doctrine/inflector/blob/1.3.x/lib/Doctrine/Common/Inflector/Inflector.php) which has some singular/plural forms predefined (`'/(p)erson$/i' => '\1eople'`)

Comment: Awesome that's what I was looking for... only you would have thought it would following naming conventions over being grammatically correct. This should at least be covered in the documentation 'plural name of the class will be used as the table name unless another name is explicitly specified' https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#table-names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Down the hood it calls `Str::plural()` on `person` as part of `person_id`, the plural version of this is `people`. So the correct naming according to the `Laravel` convention for your `persons` table is actually `people`.

So change the table to `people` or `constrained()` first parameter is the table name.

```
$table->foreignId('person_id')->constrained('persons');
```

Comment: Thanks yes already know that but I ask why it replaces 'persons' with 'people'?
 I think this is wrong and confusing so asking what's the logic for this so that I understand which tables names to avoid/watch out for.

Comment: Oh was to quick reading it, will check up on it or deleted the answer :)